# Ошибка памяти Android NDK

Tags: android, c++, android-ndk

При использовании функции `strcat()` появляется ошибка (в любой момент, если вызвать функцию не один раз):

```
char *g = strcat(strdup(f),strdup(f));
```

Ошибка такая:

```
03-31 14:59:24.163 29228-29228/optichat.testotest A/libc: invalid address or address of corrupt block 0xb8facbe0 passed to dlfree
03-31 14:59:24.164 29228-29228/optichat.testotest A/libc: Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1, fault addr 0xdeadbaad in tid 29228 (ichat.testotest)
```

Как решить эту проблему?

Comment: Тут нет ничего специфичного для [tag:c++11], да и для [tag:c++] тоже. Функция `strdup` сишная и даже не является стандартной.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Символьный массив, возвращаемый функцией `strdup(f)`, не имеет достаточно место для включения самого себя.

```
char *g = strcat(strdup(f),strdup(f));
```

Массив, используемый в качестве первого аргумента функции, должен иметь достаточно место, чтобы в него можно было дописать строку. Для приведенного вызова его размер должен быть равен по крайней мере `2 * strlen( f ) + 1`.

К тому имеет место утечка памяти, так как адрес динамически созданного массива для второго аргумента, теряется, и созданный массив невозможно удалить.

Вы не можете "на лету" создавать таким образом новые строки.

Если это C++ программа, то следует использовать стандартный класс `std::string`
Тогда можно записать просто

```
std::string s( f );
s += f;
```

Или в качестве временного выражения

```
std::string( f ) + f
```

Если же это C программа, то примерный код может выглядеть следующим образом

```
char *s = malloc( 2 * strlen( f ) + 1 );

strcat( strcpy( s, f ), f );

//...

free( s );
```

То же самое на C++ будет выглядеть как

```
char *s = new char[2 * strlen( f ) + 1];

strcat( strcpy( s, f ), f );

//...

delete [] s;
```

Comment: Спасибо, а такой вариант на плюсах будет правильным? 

char result[2*strlen(f)+1]; 
    strcpy(result,f); 
    strcat(result,f);

Comment: @Flappy Вообще-то C++ не поддерживает массивы переменной длины. Либо вам надо использовать класс std::string, либо выделять динамически память как char *res = new char[2 *strlen( f ) + 1]; strcat( strcpy( res, f ), f );

Comment: @Flappy на плюсах следует использовать `std::string`. `strcat`/`strcpy` это сишный путь!

Comment: Всем спасибо за советы, вообще зеленый в этом)